# Devising an algorithm to get $A_n$ in a series within $\log n$ operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, linear-transformations, recurrence-relations

I'm stuck on a practice problem in which I have to devise an algorithm:

Suppose a sequence integers $A_n$, and $A_0,\ldots,A_{k-1}< 50$ are all given, and each $A_i$ is a linear combination of the previous $k$ terms, ie $A_i = A_{i-1} b_1 + A_{i-2} b_2 + \dots + A_{i-k} b_k$. We know $A_0$ through $A_{k-1}$ and coefficients $b_1$ through $b_k$.

Devise an algorithm that computes $A_n \bmod 50$ in $O(\log n)$ time. You should treat $k$ as a constant, and you may assume that all arithmetic operations involving numbers of $O(\log n)$ bits take constant time.

Here's been my thought process thus far:

- using repeated squaring to get a factor of $(\log n)$
- doing something similar to fast matrix powering where I have a matrix, we'll call M that's like \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} that multiplies with \begin{bmatrix} A_{n}\\ A_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} and if you want $A_{n+1}$ you do $M^n *$ some starting vector
- But how do I account for getting only the k previous terms?

I'm mainly just stuck on how to apply repeated squaring and fast matrix powering to this algorithm. Would love a few pointers!

Comment: You are on the right track if I understand the gist of the problem.  For fixed linear combinations of $k$ previous values you can use a $k\times k$ matrix (rather than the $2\times 2$ matrix you seem to be familiar with for Fibonacci sequences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep $k$ consecutive terms as a column vector
$$A_n' := \begin{bmatrix} A_{n-k+1} & A_{n-k+2} & \ldots & A_n\end{bmatrix}^T.$$

Then define the $k \times k$ matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\\\
0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\\\
0&0&0&1&\ldots&0\\\\
\vdots&&&\vdots&&\vdots\\\\
0&0&0&0&\ldots&1\\\\
b_k & b_{k-1} & b_{k-2} & b_{k-3} & \ldots & b_1 \\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now $A_{n+1}' = MA_n'$, that is, multiplying by $M$ takes you one step forward (and still keeps the state of $k$ consecutive terms). Thus multiplying by $M^n$ takes you $n$ steps forward. If you have $M^n$, multiplying by it is a unit-cost operation since it has constant size $k \times k$ and its elements are integers smaller than $50$ (recalling that you are calculating everything modulo $50$).

It remains to find $M^n$. Now matrix multiplications $M^aM^b = M^{a+b}$ are also unit-cost operations, when $M^a$ and $M^b$ are known, so you should be able to compute $M^n$ in roughly $O(\log n)$ time. Check out [addition chain exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation).

### What about $k$?

The analysis above rests on the stipulation that $k$ is a constant. What if we include $k$ in the complexity analysis? In particular, what if $k$ is also large?

Multiplication of two $k \times k$ matrices is an $O(k^c)$ operation where in practice $c=3$ or slightly less ([theoretically we know some $c < 2.4$ algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication), and there are speculations that the exponent could be made as small as $2$). So our repeated matrix multiplication is something like $O(k^3 \log n)$. If $k$ is relatively large, this starts to play a role.

Another method would just apply the $k$-length recurrence $n-1$ times, for a total time $O(kn)$. Depending on the relative sizes of $k$ and $n$ this could be faster.

Whether there is some method between $O(k^c \log n)$ and $O(kn)$, where $c$ is the exponent in our matrix multiplication algorithm, I don't know. It would be very interesting.

At the other extreme, if $k$ is very small, one might be able to exploit the fact that we are working modulo $50$, so the $A_i'$ vector has only $50^k$ possible values. Sooner or later it will repeat itself. If you can find the period $t$, then you could do astronomically large instances fast by reducing $n$ modulo $t$.

Comment: thank you! I wonder if theres a way to do this efficiently without matrix multiplication? kinda an aside but curious what you think :)

Comment: I added some thoughts about other possibilities.